Multiple conditions in JSON Schema, draft-04
I have this field assignments:

chapters is optional inside assignments object.
type is required.
when the type is multi:
pointer value should be present in each chapters object if its
not  part of the parent assignments object.
when type is notes:
pointer is required, unless when completed is true.

{
    "assignments": [
        {
            "type": "multi",
            "pointer": "1",
            "chapters": [
                {
                    "id": "203"
                },
                {
                    "id": "204"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "multi",
            "chapters": [
                {
                    "id": "201",
                    "pointer": "3"
                },
                {
                    "id": "202",
                    "pointer": "3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "notes",
            "pointer": "4"
        },
        {
            "type": "notes",
            "completed": true
        }
    ]
}

for validating this schema with json-schema.org/draft-04, I am not sure how to satisfy all the conditions with nested-dependencies. I have tried the following schema but it is not working as expected.
As its expecting completed to be false to validate pointer, completed is optional and will only be present when it has to set as true. And for type multi its expecting pointer to be present when pointer is part of chapters.
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "assignments": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["multi", "notes"]
          },
          "pointer": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "completed": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "chapters": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "pointer": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "required": ["id"]
            }
          }
        },
        "required": ["type"],
        "dependencies": {
          "type": {
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "properties": {
                  "type": { "enum": ["multi"] }
                },
                "oneOf": [
                  {
                    "properties": {
                      "pointer": { "type": "string" }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "properties": {
                      "chapters": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "pointer": { "type": "string" }
                          },
                          "required": ["pointer"]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "properties": {
                  "type": { "enum": ["notes"] },
                  "completed": { "enum": [true] }
                }
              },
              {
                "properties": {
                  "type": { "enum": ["notes"] }
                },
                "required": ["pointer"]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["assignments"]
}

Examples:

Example 1

{
  "assignments": [
    {
      "type": "notes",
      "completed": true
    }
  ]
}


Expected Result: Should pass
Actual Result: passing


Example 2

{
  "assignments": [
    {
      "type": "notes",
      "pointer": "4"
    }
  ]
}


Expected Result: Should pass
Actual Result: notes is not a valid enum value,#/assignments/0: #: 2 subschemas matched instead of one


Example 3

{
  "assignments": [
    {
      "type": "notes"
    }
  ]
}


Expected Result: Fail with required key [pointer] not found
Actual Result: Passing


Example 4

{
  "assignments": [
    {
      "type": "multi",
      "chapters": [
        {
          "id": "201",
          "pointer": "3"
        },
        {
          "id": "202",
          "pointer": "3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Expected Result: Fail with required key [pointer] not found
Actual Result: passing


Example 5

{
  "assignments": [
    {
      "type": "multi",
      "pointer": "4",
      "chapters": [
        {
          "id": "201"
        },
        {
          "id": "202"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Expected Result: should pass
Actual Result: Failing with multi is not a valid enum value,#/assignments/0: #: 2 subschemas matched instead of one, multi is not a valid enum value,#/assignments/0: required key [pointer] not found


Example 6

{
  "assignments": [
    {
      "type": "multi",
      "chapters": [
        {
          "id": "201",
          "pointer": "4"
        },
        {
          "id": "202",
          "pointer": "4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Expected Result: should pass
Actual Result: passing


Example 7

{
  "assignments": [
    {
      "type": "multi",
      "chapters": [
        {
          "id": "201",
          "pointer": "4"
        },
        {
          "id": "202"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Expected Result: Fail with required key [pointer] not found (either pointer should be present outside 'chapters' array or should be part of every 'chapter' object )
Actual Result: passing


Are you limited to using draft4 ?

“I have tried the following schema, but it is not working as expected.” This kind of information is not working. What would work is: 1) Example #1, 1.1) short schema sample #1, 1.2) short JSON data to be validated against the schema, 1.3) expected validation result, 1.4) observed validation result, 2) Example #2...

@JeremyFiel yes,  limited to using draft4.

Unfortunately, draft-04 requires a big, verbose schema to achieve conditional behaviors.
this is much cleaner in draft-07 or newer.
I've modularized each condition in a definitions entry and then used oneOf to reference each one. The error output is extremely verbose because it needs to report on each oneOf failure during evaluation.
Couple things to consider here are the following use cases:

Example 3: type: notes and completed missing from the schema is not covered. It's not possible to evaluate a keyword that is missing.
Example 4: your expected result doesn't seem correct. You said pointer is valid at the parent OR the child, not both. So this one is passing as I think it should.

{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "assignments"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "assignments": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {},
          "pointer": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "completed": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "chapters": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "required": [
                "id"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "pointer": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/multi-pointer-in-child"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/multi-pointer-at-root"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/notes-completed:false"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/notes-completed:true"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "multi-pointer-in-child": {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "multi"
          ]
        },
        "chapters": {
          "minItems": 1,
          "items": {
            "required": [
              "pointer"
            ]
          }
        },
        "completed": {}
      },
      "required": [
        "type"
      ],
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "pointer"
        ]
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "multi-pointer-at-root": {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "multi"
          ]
        },
        "pointer": {},
        "chapters": {
          "items": {
            "not": {
              "required": [
                "pointer"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "completed": {}
      },
      "required": [
        "type"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "notes-completed:false": {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "notes"
          ]
        },
        "chapters": {},
        "completed": {
          "enum": [
            false
          ]
        },
        "pointer": {}
      },
      "required": [
        "type",
        "pointer"
      ]
    },
    "notes-completed:true": {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "notes"
          ]
        },
        "chapters": {},
        "completed": {
          "enum": [
            true
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "type"
      ],
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "pointer"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}


Unfortunately, dependencies isn't capable of expressing your constraints, but there is a way to do it using the Implication Pattern. Implication is a way of expressing conditionals and can be expressed in JSON Schema like so,
"anyOf": [
  { "not": { ... if ... } },
  { ... then ... }
]

For the "if" schema, you express the condition, and for the "then" schema, you express what you want if the "if" schema passes. So, given your first constraint,

when the type is multi: pointer value should be present in each chapters object if its not part of the parent assignments object.

The "if" schema would be,
{
  "properties": {
    "type": { "enum": ["multi"] }
  },
  "required": ["type"],
  "not": { "required": ["pointer"] }
}

And the "then" schema would be,
{
  "properties": {
    "chapters": {
      "items": { "required": ["pointer"] }
    }
  }
}

You have two of these conditional constrains, so you'll need to combine them using allOf.
"allOf": [
  { ... "multi" implication ... },
  { ... "notes" implication ... }
]

The implication pattern is hard to read if you don't know the pattern, but I think it's still better than the alternative Jeremy suggested that requires a ton of duplication. This also has the benefit of producing good error messages.
